# Assembly - How to use a variable pushed into the stack

Tags: assembly, x86

Having a bit of trouble. I have a function which is called like this:

```
;  Calc(&average, &ErrorMargin) Equivalent:
    push    ErrorMargin
    push    average
    call    Calc

;ErrorMargin and average are both declared with "dd"
```

How would I actually change the values of these variables that were pushed onto the stack? Would I use esp and go through the stack? Would I instead pop them into a register? How the heck do I access these variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it your intent to push the *values* onto the stack?  Or *pointers* to the values?

Comment: The intent is to push the pointers hopefully so that I can edit the values of those variables. Is that what it's doing? If so, how do I access the pointer?

Comment: Assuming that you don't need to create a stack frame, you use `MOV EDX, [ESP+4]` to get the address of `average`. If you create a stack frame (`PUSH EBP` `MOV EBP, ESP`), use `MOV EDX, [EBP+8]` to get address of `average`. You then use `[EDX]` to read and write the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chang. I had to use rdx and rbp to not get a seg fault, which were the registers used in the stack frame creation. However, whenever I try to use ```[rdx]``` to edit the variable, I get a seg fault, any thoughts?

Comment: Strange. Doing this will edit the Error Margin variable:
```mov rdx, [rbp-8], mov rax, 230, mov [rdx], rax```

But rbp-12 or rbp-4 will make it seg fault when trying to move rax into rdx

Comment: Moreover, it only changes the value of Error Margin for the first call. Every call afterwards has the variable unchanged.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out with the insight given by W. Chang's comment.

The Error Margin variable is accessed through:

`mov rdx, [rbp-8]`

And the Average variable is accessed with:

`mov rdx, [rbp-16]`

This method would only work on the first function call and I realized that it was due to the given template changing the location of rsp, so I accounted for it with an offset in later function calls.

Comment: The standard calling conventions for x86-64 pass args in registers where you can use them directly instead of having to load them from the stack.  Also, negative offsets from RBP are your own stack frame.  (Or the caller's private stack frame, if you haven't set up RBP as your own frame pointer).

Comment: This is from my professor. He was passing most arguments in registers but decided to throw some on the stack - not my idea. Using a positive offset would give a seg fault every single time. I'm not exactly dying to figure out why. The stack is easy to use when not used for a looping function call - I needed extra offsets to account for an offset the professor added.

Don't see why the post was down-voted, it was simply the solution to my problem.

Comment: If you're going to reference args on the stack, reference them relative to RSP.  Or set up RBP as a frame pointer for your own function.  Using `[rbp - 8]` with the caller's RBP means you're not really writing a fully separate function, just another block of the same function because you're depending on its internals, like where its RSP was relative to its RBP.  Adding room for more local variables in the caller would break this callee, defeating the purpose of a calling convention.  This is why I downvoted: it's not a proper solution, it's a happens-to-work hack for this one case.

Comment: Assembly isn't exactly intuitive when you try to do anything remotely complex. Since this is simply for a grade, I'm simply looking to code working solutions and perhaps not practical outside of an assignment kind of solutions. I understand your reasoning though.

Comment: If I was grading this, I'd explain to you why it doesn't properly solve the problem of accessing your stack args from a *separate* function, without depending on internals of the caller.  And you also chose to post it on Stack Overflow, with the implication that it's useful for future readers.  There is an easy general way to access stack args (`[rsp+8]` and `[rsp+16]` before you do anything more with RSP), and this isn't it.  Also, nothing in the question says anything about where the caller's RBP is pointing relative to its RSP, so this doesn't even answer the specific SO question you asked.